# Getting bind: address already in use even after closing the connection in golang

Tags: go, tcp, goroutine

I am building a master/slave type system in golang. When the slave(called racer) is up, it pings master telling that it is up and ready to receive data and then it starts listening on a port. The port used for pinging and listening are same but I make sure I am closing the connection after pinging. My use case is to use same port for pinging and listening but I get `bind: address already in use` error when I use the same port to listen. Sometimes it works sometimes it doesn't. What I am doing wrong?

[Complete Code](https://github.com/goku321/line-racer)

**main.go**

```
package main

import (
    "flag"
    "log"
    "strconv"
    "time"

    "github.com/goku321/line-racer/master"
    "github.com/goku321/line-racer/model"
    "github.com/goku321/line-racer/racer"
)

func main() {
    log.SetFlags(log.LstdFlags | log.Lshortfile)
    nodeType := flag.String("nodeType", "master", "type of node: master/racer")
    masterIP := flag.String("masterIP", "127.0.0.1", "ip address of master process")
    racers := flag.Int("racers", 2, "number of racers")
    racerID := flag.Int("racerID", 0, "unique racer id (0 <= id < number of racers")
    laps := flag.Int("laps", 10, "number of lap")
    ip := flag.String("ip", "127.0.0.1", "ip address of the node")
    port := flag.String("port", "3000", "port to use")
    flag.Parse()

_, err := strconv.ParseInt(*port, 10, 64)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatalf("error parsing port number: %s", *port)
}

if *nodeType == "master" {
    m := master.New(*ip, *port, *racers, *laps)
    m.GenerateLaps()
    go m.Listen()
    m.WaitForRacers()
    m.StartRace()
    m.PrintLaps()
} else {
    r := racer.New(*racerID, *ip, *port, *masterIP)
    r.SignalMaster(&model.Message{Source: r.IPAddr + ":" + r.Port})
    time.Sleep(time.Second*60)
    r.ListenForNewLap()
}
```

}

**racer.go(slave)**

```
package racer

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "log"
    "net"
    "os"
    "strconv"
    "time"

    "github.com/goku321/line-racer/model"
)

// Racer represents a racer
type Racer struct {
    ID     int
    IPAddr string
    Port   string
    Master string
    Laps   [][]model.Point
    Status string
}

// SignalMaster sends a signal to master process
// with its coordinates
func (r *Racer) SignalMaster(m *model.Message) {
    laddr, err := net.ResolveTCPAddr("tcp", r.IPAddr+":"+r.Port)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("error resolving tcp address: %s, reason: %v", r.IPAddr+":"+r.Port, err)
    }

    raddr, err := net.ResolveTCPAddr("tcp", r.Master+":3000")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("error resolving tcp address: %v", err)
    }

    for {
        conn, err := net.DialTCP("tcp", laddr, raddr)
        if err != nil {
            log.Printf("connecting to master, %v", err)
            time.Sleep(time.Second * 5)
        } else {
            m.Type = "ready"
            m.Source = strconv.Itoa(r.ID)
            m.Dest = r.Master + ":3000"
            err := json.NewEncoder(conn).Encode(&m)
            if err != nil {
                log.Fatalf("error communicating to master: %v", err)
            }
            if err = conn.Close(); err != nil {
                log.Fatal("unable to close connection")
            }
            break
        }
    }
}

// ListenForNewLap waits for master to get new coordinates
func (r *Racer) ListenForNewLap() {
    ln, err := net.Listen("tcp", ":"+r.Port)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("racer %d: %v - %v", r.ID, err, time.Now())
    }

    log.Printf("racer %d: listening on %s:%s", r.ID, r.IPAddr, r.Port)

    for {
        conn, err := ln.Accept()
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }

        go handleConnection(conn, r)
    }
}

func handleConnection(conn net.Conn, r *Racer) {
    log.Printf("racer %d: new lap from master", r.ID)

    var msg model.Message
    err := json.NewDecoder(conn).Decode(&msg)
    if err != nil {
        log.Printf("racer %d: %v", r.ID, err)
    }

    // close connection here as message has already been received
    conn.Close()

    if msg.Type == "race" {
        r.Laps = append(r.Laps, msg.Coordinates)
        r.race(msg.Coordinates)
    } else if msg.Type == "kill" {
        log.Printf("racer %d: kill signal received. racer will terminate", r.ID)
        r.printLaps()
        os.Exit(0)
    }
}
```

Comment: Dumping this much code is not helping to figure out what's going on. Where exactly do you "ping" the server?

Comment: Strange design. Why the listening port in the slave? Why not just keep the original connection open? And if you must have a listening port, why the same port as the original connection? Why not sent the listening port in the ping message? Then you can use any free port to listen.

Comment: ... and you also wouldn't have to bind the original client socket. Wins all round.

Comment: @BurakSerdar Thanks for your suggestion, I have removed unnecessary code. I am pinging the server inside ```SignalMaster``` method in ```racer.go```

Comment: @user207421Thanks for your input. Sending listening port in the ping message seems a better idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some details vary from one implementation to another, but in general, after closing a TCP connection, the underlying system (host OS, usually) has to keep it around for a little while in case of stray duplicate packets.

This connection, which is in TIME_WAIT state, can block further use of the port, making it impossible to create a new listener, unless you give the right underlying settings to the host OS.  Since Go 1.5 or so, Go automatically does this on Linux: see [issue 9929](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/9929).  What host OS are you using?

Comment: I am using mac os

Comment: (Thanks to user207421 for the wording change, I hadn't thought about lingering in TIME_WAIT vs the option SO_LINGER here. The flag to set is SO_REUSEADDR though, which isn't really obvious from either of these....) @DeepakSah: Go 1.13.5 sets SO_REUSEADDR by default on Darwin, but I'm not sure of the history here. In any case if you can avoid binding the original socket, that will sidestep the problem.

Answer (score -1):

If you still get the error, try increasing the milliseconds:

```
// Sleep a little to avoid this error "bind: address already in use"
time.Sleep(time.Millisecond * 100)

log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":7373", nil))
```

Thanks to @torek for the idea. I think it's just a notice, not really an  error. Example:

```
2023/02/17 18:10:28 listen tcp :7373: bind: address already in use exit status 1
```

With go1.20 linux/amd64 and Kernel: Linux 5.13.19-2-MANJARO